# How do I store a variable of a variable in bukkit?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

so i've been trying to make an alt detection plugin in bukkit, i'm pretty new to the api and haven't coded in a good bit but i'm not sure on how to make it work, i've tried hashmaps and i've tried other stuff too but i still don't quite understand how to do it, Basically i'm trying to get the IP of anyone that joins that isn't already in the config and put his ip there including with his IP, and then just check if his alt joins by seeing if he has the same ip as stored already, and add him to the list of usernames that are related to the IP

I thought at the start i could do something like this:

```java
String ip = event.getAddress().toString().replaceAll("/", "");
plugin.getConfig().set("IPs.", ip);
plugin.saveConfig();
if(plugin.getConfig().getString("IPs.") == s) {
    if(plugin.getConfig().get("IPs." + ip) == player.getName()) {
        plugin.getConfig().set("IPs." + s, player.getName());
        plugin.saveConfig();
    }
}
```

but i've realized I can't so i thought of trying to make a String list, and adding the list of IPs in the config, and then i realized I would need to do a weird List of lists even i technically can't then store the ip of someone and check the list of names they have since i can't check if there's a list in the name of his IP

I got really confused here, would love some help!
Thanks!

EDIT 1 My HashMap code i used:

```
 // s is the ip string
    HashMap<String,String[]> map = new HashMap<String,String[]>();
                String[] names = new String[10];
                names[0] = player.getName();
                map.put(s, names);
                saveHashMap(map);
```

saveHashMap:

```
public void saveHashMap(HashMap<String, String[]> hm) {

    for (String key : hm.keySet()) {
        plugin.getConfig().set("IPs."+key, hm.get(key));
        }
            plugin.saveConfig();
    }

}
```

To test i tried this:

```
    HashMap<String,String[]> test = loadHashMap();
    String[] a = test.get(s);

    System.out.println(a[0]);
```

loadHashMap:

```
    public HashMap<String, String[]> loadHashMap() {
    HashMap<String, String[]> hm = new HashMap<String,String[]>();
    for (String key : plugin.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("IPs").getKeys(false)) {
        hm.put(key, (String[]) plugin.getConfig().get("IPs."+key));
        }

    return hm;
    }
```

Comment: A hashmap would probably be the right way to do it.

Comment: @JakobF i've tried that, the problem is its for some reason saved it in the config like this:
`IPs:
  '123':
    '123:
      '123':
        '123':
        - Offlical
        - null
        - null
        - null
        - null
        - null
        - null
        - null
        - null
        - null
`

Comment: Could you add some code showing how you did that?

Comment: Be sure to correct your String comparison by replacing `someString == "..."` with `"...".equals(someString)`. The reason why I reordered the strings is, you get the `null` check for free.

Comment: @JakobF i'll add it to the post one second

Comment: And what is the problem with that, what is the ouput or error?

Comment: @JakobF https://pastebin.com/5qY3Vx3B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the gamepedia [entry](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Configuration_API_Reference#The_Configuration_Object) you should save HashMaps like this:

```java
getConfig().createSection(String path, Map< String, Object > map)
```

and retrieve them like this:

```java
getConfig().getConfigurationSection("path.to.map").getValues(false)
```

You then need to cast the map to the types you want.

Comment: I can't cast my map to Map<String,Object>, other than that, the map it returns is a Map<String,Object> and i can't cast it back to a String[] because when i do that it gives me an nullpointer error, i can only make it a string, which doesn't really help me: `[Offlical, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]`, thanks for the suggestion anyway

Comment: Well this partially worked! I just swapped the String array with a List and used `getConfig().getConfigurationSection("IPs").getList(s)` Thanks for the help!